# Centos 5 restarts Apache server with different httpd.conf after I install yum php-devel

Tags: linux, centos

Currently, I am using Centos 5 to run linux server.

A day ago, I installed php-devel by using 'yum php-devel' on ssh.

I tried to restart the Apache server with this command

```
service httpd restart
```

However, the apache server reads different httpd.conf file.

It suppose to read the httpd.conf file where locates '/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf' file

However, it reads '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' now.

therefore, it makes this error.

```
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Do you know why this is happening?

is there a way to reset direction of httpd.conf file when the Apache server restarts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this one.

The problem was the server was using different httpd.conf file.

So I checked the route one more time and changed it to original httpd.conf route.